# Passing data from My SQL to ANDROID

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have a requirement in which i want to display the data from MySQL in Android TextView through PHP.This is how the interface looks like

```
Casual Leave
  Leave Taken:
  Leave Remaining:

Privilege Leave
  Leave Taken:
  Leave Remaining:
```

I am a beginner in android Programming.I do know how to make connection through PHP....I Wanted help for passing the data to and fro and displaying it.Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The better one is to create a web service in `php`, and consume that `web service` through `android`,then Your client (`Android application`) sends an `HTTP` request to the `REST` service.

Answer (score 1):

you can parse data from android to mysql Db and mysql db to android by using JSon. it is easy and fast way to handle data transfer between mysql db to android and vice-versa. 
  For doing that you needed php as interface. Follow the following link [mysqlphpandroid](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/09/25/table-values-mysql-database-show-android-tables/)

Comment: Thanks for the link.will try that and come back.

Answer (score 0):

You must do the following things:

- Request data from server. Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553156/android-getting-data-from-server)!
- Parse data (if its format is JSON or XML)
- Display it on the textview in html format .Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview)!